# Gandhi's superstitious gambit

Tags: philosophy, advaita, karma

Mahatma Gandhi attributed the 1934 earthquake that killed 20,000 ppl to collective karma. i guess he was attempting to arouse the emotions of his countrymen regarding the caste system.  as you probably know, he was open to many religions, philosophies, and viewpoints.

is there any basis for collective karma in vedanta philosophy?  is it the brainchild of advaita thinking? or merely suspension of disbelief?

[here](https://scroll.in/article/724133/suggesting-religious-reasons-for-quakes-isnt-new-mahatma-gandhi-did-that-in-1934) is what he gandhi said:

> “Visitations like droughts, floods, earthquakes and the like, though
> they seem to have only physical origins are for me somehow connected
> with man’s morals. Therefore, I instinctively, felt that the
> earthquake was a visitation for the sin of untouchability. Of course,
> Sanatanists have a perfect right to say that it was due to my crime of
> preaching against untouchability. My belief is a call to repentance
> and self purification. I admit my utter ignorance of the working of
> the laws of nature. But even as I cannot help believing in God though
> I am unable to prove his existence to the sceptics, in like manner, I
> cannot prove the connection of the sin of untouchability with the
> Bihar visitation even though the connection is instinctively felt by
> me.”

Comment: we all collectively cause global warming, don't we ? so we would all collectively face the karma. but in Bhagavan's book, there is no such thing as collective. it is just individual. but it looks collective because all individuals happened to do the same karma, hence experience same consequences. untouchability is not a sin. it is a virtue. i practice untouchability with my own body, what to speak of other people. i cannot use my fingers to scratch any itch on my body nails during japa, i have to use a stick. if i scratch with nails i have to get up, wash my hands, do achamana, only then japa

Comment: if i attend nature's call, i cannot touch anyone until i wash my hands, feet, mouth. if i touch anyone who has not washed their hands, feet, mouth after they attended nature's call, i have to wash my own hands, feet, mouth and do achamana. the number of rules that brahmins have to follow is insanely high and they would be bathing all day if all sorts of unclean people were allowed to accidentally or purposely touch day. it is no different from a clean lab in semiconductor fabrication or a biohazard medical research lab where scientists wear white hazmat suits and gloves to avoid contamination

Comment: because extreme purity is needed for the rituals that brahmins perform to bear fruit.